# Does bundle update install gems that haven't been installed before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

This is just a general question about `bundle install` and `bundle update` and it's literally as simple as the title. Does `bundle update` do `bundle install` to the files that weren't installed beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `bundle update` does two things:

1. Update `Gemfile.lock` to the latest versions available, using `Gemfile` as the source of information for updating `Gemfile.lock`.
2. Run `bundle install` to make sure all these gems are present in your system.

So yes, if you add a gem to `Gemfile` and then run `bundle update`, it will install this new gem for you too.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.

`bundle update` will install the latest version of all gems listed in your gemfile, regardless of what you have in `Gemfile.lock`. E.g. if you were to add `rails` to your `Gemfile` without previously having run `bundle install` bundle update would install the `rails` gem.

> To do this, run bundle update, which will ignore the Gemfile.lock, and resolve all the dependencies again

[source](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_update.html#update-all-gems)

Comment: And I think this one can install new gems. But only it such gems will be dependency of gems listed in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle Update will actually update the versions of the gems that you have bundled, see: http://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html#NAME

Whereas Bundle Install will install the missing gems that were not previously installed, see: http://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-install.1.html#NAME